# Apache Nutch one document for each item in RSS Feed

Tags: apache, solr, rss, nutch

I'm trying to build an application with Apache Nutch that adds to the DB several documents, one for each item in a RSS Feed.

From my understanding, when now it parses a feed, it creates a unique Solr Document, with all the content concatenated

```
<item>
     <title>Comment 1</title>
     <link>http://www.link.com/a/#comment-2555842742</link>
     <description>document text1</description>
     <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">12321 Borland</dc:creator>
     <pubDate>Mon, 07 Mar 2016 06:48:35 -0000</pubDate>
  </item>
  <item>
     <title>>Comment 2</title>
     <link>http://www.link.com/a/#comment-2555590727</link>
     <description>document text2</description>
     <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">12321</dc:creator>
     <pubDate>Mon, 07 Mar 2016 00:48:34 -0000</pubDate>
  </item>
```

Instead I would like to be able to return 2 ParseResult instead of only one: one for each item in the feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the RSS feeds are parsed by the `parse-tika` plugin, see https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/parse-plugins.xml#L31-L34, which by default identifies the links inside the RSS feed as Outlinks of the original feed URL. This outlinks are then stored for later fetching, parsing, etc. This could be checked if you run the command:

```
$ bin/nutch parsechecker http://humanos.uci.cu/feed/
```

The output should be something like:

```
...
---------
Url
---------------

http://humanos.uci.cu/feed/
---------
ParseData
---------

Version: 5
Status: success(1,0)
Title: humanOS
Outlinks: 10
...
```

This basically reports that 1 URL was successfully parsed and 10 outlinks were found.

To get the output that you want, you need to use the `feed` plugin. So first, activate the `feed` plugin in the `plugin.include` attribute of your `nutch-site.xml` file.

Once this is done you still need to instruct Nutch to use the `feed` parser first (which uses the ROME library underneath). To accomplish this edit the `conf/parse-plugins.xml` file, find the entry: `<mimeType name="application/rss+xml">` and leave it like:

```
<mimeType name="application/rss+xml">
    <plugin id="feed" />
    <plugin id="parse-tika" />
</mimeType>
```

In this case if you try again the `parsechecker` command the output will be different, and once you index into Solr/ES you should see more documents: 1 for the original feed plus one for each item in your feed.

Keep in mind that this new documents will only have as the `content` field the `description` extracted from the feed which could be fairly incomplete.

If you need to write a more customized logic, the `ParseResult` class allows to have "subdocuments" (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/ParseResult.java#L30-L41).

Comment: I tried to switch  feed and parse-tika as you suggested, but, now parsechecker doesn't show anything. Is it correct?
When we specify the parser, is only the first one considered (and the next ignored)?

Comment: Did you enable the feed plugin in the `nutch-site.xml` file? This is the output of the `bin/nutch parsechecker` command **before** swapping the `feed` and `tika-parser` plugins in the `parse-plugins.xml` file https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/878c9e03f341e6e8ef992cad3eec2596. And this is the output **after** the swap is done: https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/75b52ae5eaa66b32be72f764b5003c50 In both cases the command works fine, but the output is different.

Comment: I'm using the master branch of the versione 1.x. The response is totally empty with the feed plugin https://gist.github.com/FreCap/3334a208c3890adf2dd42a9aef4f04e3

Comment: It works! the url normalizer was configured in such a way that considered all the urls the same (truncating all the urls), overriding the existing values in the map and therefore not returning multiple results

Comment: Glad it worked!, I've just tested with a build of the 1.x trunk/master and also worked fine (I was using a local copy of the 1.11 branch)